# Express $x^{x^{x^{x^{x...}}}}$ in the form of a limit.

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations, exponential-function, exponentiation, recursion

I want to rewrite $x^{x^{x^{x^{x...}}}}$ as a limit in the form of $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(n)$$
I have defined the recurrence relation
$$a_x(n) = x^{a_x(n-1)}$$
and
$$a_x(1) = x$$
So, I can write the limit as:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_x(n)$$
but since my main goal is to evaluate the limit for $x = \sqrt2$, i.e $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{\sqrt2}(n)$, this notation won't help. Please add some hints as to how should I proceed with solving the limit too. [The page](https://math.hmc.edu/funfacts/tower-of-powers/) where I found this says that one may set $A = x^{x^{x^{x^{x...}}}}$, then $x^A = A$, so $x = A^{1\over A}$, which implies that for $A = 2,4$, $x = \sqrt2$. I have trouble finding which one is correct (using a calculator, I found it is very close to 2 for $n = 10$), but the page says something about finding the limit and leaves it there for the reader. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you just write $x^{x^x}$ usually $x^{(x^x)}$ is meant, and with this interpretation $x=\sqrt{2}$ shoudl quickly diverge to infinity. Do you mean  $(x^x)^x$?

Comment: **If** there is a limit $L$ of $a_x(n),$ then you will have $L=x^L.$ But you have to show the limit exists. Aside: I recommend using $b_n(x)$ rather than $a_x(n).$ We more often use indexes as integers and function arguments as reals. Your choice isn't wrong, it just reads ... odd.

Comment: @quarague Actually, it doesn't diverge. I understand why you'd guess it does, but it doesn't.

Comment: There are other related, but different, questions on the site.  For examples, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1948778/ , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4045353/ , and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1566845/ .

Comment: For future reference, [approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E%7Bx%5E%7Bx%5E%7Bx%5E%7Bx...%7D%7D%7D%7D%24&p=1) is a "math aware" search engine which is useful for finding results like this.

Comment: @quarague For a quick argument why that isn't the case, note $(\sqrt{2})^x$ is an increasing function of $x$, so whenever $x < 2$ you have $(\sqrt{2})^x < (\sqrt{2})^2 = 2$.  Now induct on the height of any finite tower: $\sqrt{2} < 2$, so $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2} < 2$, so $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}} < 2$, and so on, showing every such tower of finite height is less than $2$ (definitely not diverging)